# Server side equivalent of "top.location.href"

Tags: asp.net, radwindow

I'm in 'Home' page. From there 'Child' page is called in a radwindow. Now on a click event of 'Child' page, I want to close the radwindow and reload page 'Home' page.

Inorder to achieve this, on the click event of a button defined in 'Child' page. I am calling a JavaScript function:-

```
function ReloadHome 
{
    var abc = 'Home.aspx';
    top.location.href = abc;
}
```

**Question:-** How to close radwindow and then navigate or reload 'Home' page, using a server side method. Not the javascript mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

Close :

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { window.close();}</script>")
```

Redirect :

```
Response.Redirect("...Your url");
```

Comment: Aghilas:- This opens up the destination URL in the radwindow itself, instead of close the radwindow and opening\reloading the base page.